# Android custom option menu item

Tags: android, menuitem, android-actionbar-compat, optionmenu

everyone! I have question for Android guys. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

So my problem:

I have application with ActionBarCompat and in this action bar I have a lot of different hiden menu items, which appear only if user click on menu button at action bar. Also I have couple menu items at action bar, which always visible.

I need some customization for one of visible menu item. When user click on this menu item (let's say it would be "Add new" menu item), I need to show different menu in this case. And if user click on standart menu item, it should act like usually.

So I really confused. And I have no idea how I can do it. Maybe someone had the same problem or similar. Thank you!

Screenshot for better understanding:

[image]