# How to customize Spinner's Dropdown background

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to customize Android Spinner's Dropdown background. Not for all spinners used in the application, but only one of them.
After doing some research I found this Style in the sdk's styles.xml but I don't know how to inherit it and use it from my Spinner.

```
<style name="Widget.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="dropDownSelector">@drawable/list_selector_background</item>
    <item name="popupBackground">@drawable/spinner_dropdown_background</item>
    <item name="dropDownVerticalOffset">-10dip</item>
    <item name="dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Specifically I want to get ride of the default theme's borders (arrows in red) and use the full width.

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `Custom Adapter` and change the background of your textview .

Comment: why not you trying this with a sliding drawer make SpinnerItem one as textview and on click of that shows sliding drawer with the following entry you have

Comment: Maybe I wasn't enough clear. I want to change the border of the ListPopupWindow used internally by PopupWindow when opened as DropDown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PopupMenu:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, someButton);
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
// switch your menu item and do something..
return true;
}
});
popup.show();
```

After that you can customize you menu items: [Android custom option menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152289/android-custom-option-menu-item)

Comment: Yes, PopupMenu can be a solution